# Application error : The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)

Tags: ionic2

On calling my web service from my app.component.ts file I am getting the below error when I run the app in VS Emulator for Android. Can someone please provide a solution?

[image]

In the ngOnInit() life cycle hook of app.component.ts I am accessing the data from the web service class

**app.component.ts(excerpt)**

```
ngOnInit()
  {

    this.myDataService.openWebMwthod()
         .subscribe((response)=>{
            this.datas = response;
            JSON.stringify(this.datas);
            alert("here"+this.datas);

            if(this.datas == null || this.datas == "")
            {
              this.nav.setRoot(this.accessDeniedPage, {showFooter : false});
            }
            else
            {
              this.nav.setRoot(this.homePage, {showFooter : false});
            }
        });  

  }
```

Below is my Web Service class excerpt where I am making a REST call:

**my-mobile.dataservice(excerpt)**

```
public openWebMwthod() : Observable<any>{

    this.initializeApp();

    let details = {
                     "EmpID" : this.sapId
                   };

    let body = JSON.stringify(details);

    let headers = new Headers(
        {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',    
        }
      );

    let options = new RequestOptions({headers:headers});

    return this.http.post(URL,body,options)
             .map( (res) => res.json())


  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add this code to your config.xml

```
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
```